# why can't join 2 tables with different num of rows on id?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I need to divide time from table A by table B to find relative completion time in % of a task.
The time column shows the time student needed to finish a task.

if the total time it took was 2 min, and the attempt time was 1 min, then the relative time is 50%

One table has 30 rows - it' s a derived table that shows total time,

another 59 rows - time it took for each step without summation,

common field is named st_id (step_id).

The first table A :

```
+-------+---------+
| st_id | time    |
+-------+---------+
| 10    | 0:00:28 |
| 11    | 0:01:51 |
| 12    | 0:10:09 |
| 13    | 0:03:44 |
| 14    | 0:16:44 |
| 15    | 0:19:12 |
| 16    | 0:03:43 |
| 17    | 0:07:56 |
| 18    | 0:06:19 |
| 19    | 0:31:14 |
| 20    | 0:11:50 |
| 81    | 0:14:12 |
| 82    | 0:18:59 |
| 83    | 0:30:24 |
| 84    | 0:11:50 |
| 85    | 0:40:35 |
| 86    | 1:28:57 |
| 87    | 0:24:10 |
| 88    | 0:51:53 |
| 100   | 0:05:31 |
| 101   | 0:13:41 |
| 103   | 0:11:50 |
| 104   | 0:22:18 |
| 105   | 0:35:18 |
| 106   | 0:55:02 |
| 107   | 0:42:02 |
| 108   | 0:08:52 |
| 109   | 1:07:07 |
| 110   | 0:11:50 |
| 111   | 0:11:55 |
+-------+---------+
```

another table has 59 rows - table B:

```
+------------+---------+---------------+
| student_id | st_id   | time          |
+------------+---------+---------------+
| 59         | 10      | 0:00:28       |
| 59         | 11      | 0:01:11       |
| 59         | 12      | 0:06:09       |
| 59         | 13      | 0:02:24       |
| 59         | 14      | 0:00:05       |
| 59         | 14      | 0:00:04       |
| 59         | 14      | 0:00:20       |
| 59         | 14      | 0:00:23       |
| 59         | 14      | 0:09:42       |
| 59         | 14      | 0:00:10       |
| 59         | 15      | 0:11:44       |
| 59         | 15      | 0:00:08       |
| 59         | 16      | 0:02:23       |
| 59         | 17      | 0:04:53       |
| 59         | 17      | 0:00:23       |
| 59         | 18      | 0:00:07       |
| 59         | 18      | 0:03:19       |
| 59         | 18      | 0:00:53       |
| 59         | 19      | 0:00:07       |
| 59         | 19      | 0:00:29       |
| 59         | 19      | 0:00:10       |
| 59         | 19      | 0:00:06       |
| 59         | 19      | 0:00:04       |
| 59         | 19      | 0:00:07       |
| 59         | 19      | 0:00:24       |
| 59         | 19      | 0:00:08       |
| 59         | 19      | 0:00:08       |
| 59         | 19      | 0:02:11       |
| 59         | 19      | 0:00:10       |
| 59         | 19      | 0:15:50       |
| 59         | 20      | 0:07:10       |
| 59         | 81      | 0:08:52       |
| 59         | 82      | 0:11:31       |
| 59         | 82      | 0:00:08       |
| 59         | 83      | 0:00:04       |
| 59         | 83      | 0:00:08       |
| 59         | 83      | 0:00:51       |
| 59         | 83      | 0:00:15       |
| 59         | 83      | 0:17:46       |
| 59         | 84      | 0:07:10       |
| 59         | 85      | 0:24:35       |
| 59         | 86      | 0:53:14       |
| 59         | 86      | 0:00:23       |
| 59         | 87      | 0:07:10       |
| 59         | 87      | 0:07:40       |
| 59         | 88      | 0:31:13       |
| 59         | 100     | 0:03:31       |
| 59         | 101     | 0:08:21       |
| 59         | 103     | 0:07:10       |
| 59         | 104     | 0:13:38       |
| 59         | 105     | 0:21:18       |
| 59         | 106     | 0:33:02       |
| 59         | 107     | 0:07:10       |
| 59         | 107     | 0:18:12       |
| 59         | 108     | 0:05:32       |
| 59         | 109     | 0:40:27       |
| 59         | 110     | 0:07:10       |
| 59         | 111     | 0:07:15       |
+------------+---------+---------------+
```

I tried to inner join by step_id, but it gives me the error:
"derived table has diff num of rows"

But i m only trying to join those that exist in both tables? that's how inner join works?

I have both tables inside with clause, they pull attempt time data for student_id = 59:

```
with  step_helper(st_id, t) as (  

select  step_id, sec_to_time(sum(t)) as total_time from (select  step_id,
case when (submission_time - attempt_time) > 3600 then sec_to_time((select * from s1))
else sec_to_time((submission_time - attempt_time)) end as t
from step_student  where student_id = 59)k
group by step_id),

time_attempt(st_id, t) as (
select student.student_id, step.step_id,
case when (submission_time - attempt_time) > 3600 then sec_to_time((select * from s1))
else sec_to_time((submission_time - attempt_time)) end as Время_попытки   
from step_student  inner join student on student.student_id = step_student.student_id 
inner join step on step.step_id = step_student.step_id where student.student_id = 59)
```

this inner joining the 2 tables above does not work:

```
SELECT *FROM  time_attempt INNER JOIN step_helper ON time_attempt.st_id = step_helper.st_id
```

> In definition of view, derived table or common table expression,
> SELECT list and column names list have different column counts

Comment: There's no step_id here

Comment: @Strawberry its not about st_id or step_id - i tried correct naming and it did not work, i will change naming so people have no doubts about this obvious thing

Comment: Why did you abbreviate "step_id" to "st_id"? And could you tell us which table has which name?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware it s' not significant here, the problem is that despite the common field and inner join - it still gives me bug that num of rows are not the same..

Comment: You should describe what you are trying to achieve and not just post your code.

Comment: I find it very significant, "step_id" is a better name than "st_id". Anyway, the syntax for an inner join is `SELECT * FROM <one table> AS A INNER JOIN <another table> AS B ON A.st_id = B.st_id`.

Comment: @rf1234 i m sorry sir, i will update and post the problem description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here `time_attempt(st_id, t) as (`. The columns in `SELECT` sub-query for `time_attempt` are 3 however you only list 2. As per [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html)

> The number of names in the list must be the same as the number of columns in the result set.

Therefore, your option is either listing all three columns from the result set `time_attempt(st_id, t, ttt) as (` or don't list them at all `time_attempt as (`.

**Update:**

[Here is an update fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=966d6d37ad338fd9920f18c3611ce13f) to prove a point that it's not about row differences that return the error.

Comment: omg, rly? is it about not 30 vs 59 but num of columns i pass?

Comment: No, the 30 and 59 results from both of your tables are called *rows*. The error specifically returned `... SELECT list and column names list have different column counts` - *columns* .. not rows

Comment: Regardless, the specific error is reproducible due to column count mismatch, as you can see in the fiddle. Therefore, upon lookup into MySQL documentation about `WITH` statement, it's stated as what I posted above.